# Laravel - latest() chained with where() behavior

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have a many-to-many table with created_at and the foreign keys student_id and status_id.

For each student, I want to retrieve an entry only if the latest one has status_id = 1.

I tried it like this: (it's a chain of queries, in this case $query would be Student::where(something else))

```
$query->whereHas('statusuri', function($query) use ($statusuri) {
                $query->latest('status_student.created_at')->where('status_id', 1);
});
```

(statusuri is the many-to-many relationship)

but I get a different result from what I need.

It does the where clause first and then latest(). Basically, it retrieves the last entry which matches the where.

I want to search for each student, the latest entry and if the where clause matches it, get that entry. If not, don't return anything.

Is that possible with Eloquent?

Thanks.

Comment: Try moving ```latest``` out of the closure

Comment: Would you mind showing where do you think, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a "has one of many" relationship : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#advanced-has-one-of-many-relationships

You can make a relationship in your Student model:

```
public function latestStatus()
{
    return $this->hasOne(StatusStudent::class)->ofMany([
        'created_at' => 'max',
        'id' => 'max',
    ], function ($query) {
        $query->where('status_id', 1);
    });
}
```

Edit: works only for Laravel 8+

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Laravel 6. :(

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu, edited my post to add solution for Laravel 6

Comment: It still doesn't work as expected. :( I get the same number of students retrieved. What I wanted is retrieve the ones which have the latest status equal to 1. If they have a status equal to 1 but it is not the latest, don't retrieve it.

Comment: I found out why. the SQL generated doesn't include latest(): "select * from `students` where `conducator_doctorat_id` = ? and exists (select * from `status_student` where `students`.`id` = `status_student`.`student_id` and `status_id` in (?))

Comment: even though I included it: public function latestStatus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(StatusStudent::class)->latest('status_student.created_at');
    }

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu sorry, my solution didn't work for laravel 6. Can't figure out a solution for Laravel versions before 8th. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use the where and latest methods together in a subquery, like this:

```
$query->whereHas('statusuri', function($query) use ($statusuri) {
    $query->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('status_id', 1)
              ->latest('status_student.created_at');
    });
});
```

Comment: SQL generated: "select * from `students` where `conducator_doctorat_id` = ? and exists (select * from `statusuri` inner join `status_student` on `statusuri`.`id` = `status_student`.`status_id` where `students`.`id` = `status_student`.`student_id` and (`status_id` = ?)) . no latest()